# UITableViewController's table resize

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController and I need to resize the table vertically.

**I can't use a UIViewController with a table inside**.

There is a method?

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use a table in a view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a `UITableViewController`, it may be easier just to use a standard `UIViewController`, with a `UITableView` property.

E.g.:

```
@interface ContentsPopover : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
//...
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *theTableView;
//...
@end
```

That way, inside your `UIViewController` you can have the following code (possibly in viewDidLoad):

```
theTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:/*...*/ style:UITableViewStylePlain];

theTableView.delegate = self;
theTableView.dataSource = self;
theTableView.scrollEnabled = YES;

[self.view addSubview:theTableView];

// You can now change theTableView's frame property as needed
```

This is handy for when a `UITableViewController` wasn't quite what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

This is only possible if your `UITableViewController` view is manually added to another superview. However, if you are planning to use the table view in a navigation controller or as a modal sheet you do not have control over the table view's size.

To have full control over the table view size:

1. Make you own subclass of `UIViewController` with `UITableView` outlet and a resource file.
2. Place a UITableView on top of its content `view` and resize it accordingly.
3. Make your view controller implement `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols.
4. Connect outlets.